# Add 1 if checked correct answer

Tags: c#, asp.net

For example i have two radio button list:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" >
<asp:ListItem Value="1">&nbsp;1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">&nbsp;2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">&nbsp;3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">&nbsp;4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl2_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
<asp:ListItem Value="1">&nbsp;1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">&nbsp;2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">&nbsp;3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">&nbsp;4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

protected void rbl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Correct Answer.";
    }
    else
    {

        Label1.Text = "Incorect";

    }

}
protected void rbl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbl2.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {


        Label2.Text = "Correct Answer";
    }
    else
    {

        Label2.Text = "Incorect";

    }
```

and I want to   if rbl1 selectedindex =1 add 1 value to a label (like Lable3) to show also  if rbl2 selectedindex = 0, again sum 1 with previous score in label3.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double click the list in designer and it will create `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Write your code in there.

Comment: can you please post the label code and OnSelectedIndexChanged method. Please see here for https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve